# Saving text as images - PHP

Tags: php, string, image

I have a question about saving text/strings as images in PHP. Since I want to protect data on my site, I want to convert text and save it as image files in a folder on a server (before displaying it). Is there a way to do it, or maybe a better solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into `openssl_encrypt` and `openssl_decrypt` if you're interested in protecting data.

Answer (score 1):

> If you wish to convert Text/String into image, you can try **ImageMagick** or **GD**.

Detail about **ImageMagick (Imagick extension)** is available at http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Detail about **GD** at http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

> `getimagettftext()` function from GD can be useful, see detail at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php
>
> `Imagick::annotateImage()` function from Imagick can be useful, see detail at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save text as an image, not overlay it on another image, then you should use label: or caption: or tango: in ImageMagick and not annotate.

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/. Then find the equivalent command in Imagick. For example, https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.labelimage.php

You can use the equivalent of -annnotate, but then you have to create an background image onto which to write the text.

The advantage of label: for example is that it creates an image automatically.